# How to open up CSV in excel to a list of all words?

Tags: excel

So i have cells in excel with values. i want them separated and get a list of all the words.

```
EDF, renewables, nuclear, France, USA
red, yellow
```

to

```
EDF
renewables
nuclear
France
USA
red
yellow
```

Comment: Data > Text to Column then copy and paste using transpose.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitDown()
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant
    With Worksheets(1)
        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(i, "A").Value2, ", ")) Then
                arr = Split(.Cells(i, "A").Value2, ", ")
                .Cells(i + 1, "A").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).EntireRow.Insert
                .Cells(i, "A").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(arr)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```